# "Command not invoked properly" Setting up laravel homestead with Vagrant

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I am trying to set up a a vagrant laravel homestead box. I have both vagrant and virtualbox installed on my Xubuntu 14.04 machine. To do this I'm running the following command

```
user@home: $ vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

Then I get the following error

```
This command was not invoked properly. The help for this command is
available below.

Usage: vagrant box add <name> <url> [--provider provider] [-h]
```

I'm doing this exactly how the laravel and vagrant documentation shows. Why is this not working? Do I need a url?

Comment: What is the Vagrant version you are using? `vagrant --version`

Older Vagrant versions doesn't support this syntax and need to be told specific URL to look for instead of using Vagrantcloud.com

Comment: I'm using version 1.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is correct for versions 1.5+.
If you older Vagrant you need go to `https://vagrantcloud.com/<BOX_NAME>/versions` and copy the full link to the latest active version of you box. (`<BOX_NAME>` in your case is `laravel/homestead`)

Then you can download like this:

`vagrant box add 'laravel/homestead' https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead/version/9/provider/virtualbox.box --provider virtualbox`

However I strongly advice to update your Vagrant for the latest one.

Comment: I upgraded and it worked. I really surprised me how hard it was to find that documentation for 1.4.3. I couldn't find that url anywhere.

Comment: Yes, vagrant is rapidly developed and lots of stuff is being added between versions.